# Chrome: Found a crash, is it a security vulnerability?

Tags: macos, chrome

I have been able to make Google Chrome crash, and I was wondering if there are tools or heuristics to determine whether or not the crash is a security vulnerability.

How can I determine if a Chrome crash is also a security vulnerability?

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a crashdump. Could you post a stack trace, or the dump file?

Comment: Where can I find the stack trace, or the dump file?

Comment: Not sure on OSX. Try a Google for "OSX chrome crash dump location" or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest reading [Best way to triage crashes found via fuzzing, on Linux?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6998/971), which describes exactly how to do a first-pass triage at assessing the likelihood that the crash is also a security problem.  Tools like !exploitable and Valgrind memcheck are your friend.

If it passes the first-level check, the next step is probably to report it to the Chrome folks and let them evaluate it in greater detail.