# Google Chrome Crash Report Analysis

Tags: web-browser, chrome, reverse-engineering, fuzzing, debugging

I am new to the field of crash analysis. I recently, by accident, happened to crash Google Chrome. I do not know the reason as to why the crash really happened. I'd like to know it in depth though.

When the crash happened, there was a Crash report that was generated. I have saved that report in a text file on my system, as I did not know what to do with it at the out start.

Now I have heard people in the info sec world talk about things like, analyzing and reversing a crash dump, fuzzing a crash dump etc. and trying to reproduce the crash.

I am interested in understanding how these things are done and in the first place what they actually are. I need help with resources that can help me understand how to analyze and reproduce a crash etc. I happened to come across: -[Chrome: Found a crash, is it a security vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18012/chrome-found-a-crash-is-it-a-security-vulnerability) and [Best way to triage crashes found via fuzzing, on Linux?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6998/best-way-to-triage-crashes-found-via-fuzzing-on-linux) but these resources seemed a bit advance and not very basic. Also googling up gave me some resources of how to analyze a BSOD in Windows, but I could not find anything relevant for Google Chrome Crash Analysis.

Please help provide some good resources where I can understand these concepts.

My Platform is Mac OSX 10.9.2 and my Google Chrome is Version 35.0.1916.153.

Comment: Is the crash reproducible?

Comment: @RobW Hi. I do not know that yet. I would like to investigate it and know the same.

Comment: When I find a crash in Chrome, I usually try to check whether it is reproducible, and if it is, run it in gdb. Have you already read http://www.chromium.org/developers/crash-reports and http://www.chromium.org/developers/decoding-crash-dumps?